# Not read from remote repository

Tags: git

Устанавливаю polymer cli, пишет

> does not appear to be a git repository, Could not read from remote
>   repository, Please make sure you have the correct access rights.

Что это значит и что делать?

Comment: думаю, не все знают, что такое polimer cli и как именно Вы его устанавливаете. Но скорее всего каким то образом там фигурирует git репозиторий и он либо сломан, либо не существует по выбранному адресу.